# What’s the normal form of this function of the picture

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions

[image: A barbell shaped figure]

Sorry I know it must be a silly question.But I spent a lot of time to find it out but failed.I want to use it to fit the red blood cell cross sections so that I can calculate the volume.
I try sth like $\sqrt{a-x^2}-\sqrt{b-y^2}=0$ by memory(because I have done similar question in my senior high school,but I actually forget it ……)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like
$$r=a+b\cos^2\theta$$
in polar coordinates.  You could also fiddle around with the exponent: $r=a+b|\cos\theta|^3$ might be even better.
[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.i go to learn the polar coordinates right now (stupid am i wuwuwuwu)